# performSelector causes leak because not right type in objective c

Tags: objective-c, selector, nsnumber

I have the following code:

```
SEL moveAlongBoth = @selector(moveAlongX:andY:);
if ([p1 respondsToSelector:moveAlongBoth]) {
    [p1 performSelector: moveAlongBoth
             withObject: [NSNumber numberWithInt:1]
             withObject: [NSNumber numberWithInt:1]];
}
```

I am getting a "performSelector may cause leak" warning.
But

```
[p1 moveAlongX:1 andY:1];
```

Works just fine.

I understand that I am getting the error because the values are set to (int) in the implementation and I am using NSNumber. Without changing the implementation, how would I go about declaring a number value to int (if possible)?

Comment: Is this an error or a warning?

Comment: Sorry, warning. But the result is incorrect.

Comment: Well, then have a look to the result. It is a warning because ARC cannot "see" beyond performSelector.

Comment: Why are you using `performSelector` when you know the specific method and parameters?

Comment: "I understand that I am getting the error because the values are set to (int) in the implementation and I am using NSNumber." No. That has nothing to do with it. You will always get this warning when calling the `performSelector:` series of methods, because some methods (e.g. `alloc`, `retain`, `new`, `copy`, `mutableCopy`) return an owned reference and others do not, but it's impossible to tell whether the method being called is one of those at compile time.

Comment: The fact that your method takes `int` and you are passing `NSNumber *` (a pointer) is another problem. You are invoking undefined behavior, and, even in the best case, your method will get huge numbers corresponding to the addresses of the `NSNumber` objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why can't you just do this:

```
if ([p1 respondsToSelector:@selector(moveAlongX:andY:)]) {
    [(id)p1 moveAlongX:1 andY:1];
}
```

By the way, the [Cocoa naming convention](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/Articles/NamingMethods.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001282-BCIGIJJF) would have you call this method `moveAlongX:y:`.

Comment: Thanks! The instructions wanted us to use  respondsToSelector and for some reason, I didn't even think to do it this way!

Answer (score 0):

With regard to the second part. If you are in charge of the classes that may be the type of `p1`, then you could define a `protocol` with `moveAlongBoth::` and instead of checking with `performSelector` check wit `conformsToProtocol`. Let's say the protocol's name is `CanMoveAlong` then you can cast it to

```
id <CanMoveAlong> canDo = (id<CanMoveAlong>)p1;
```

after you checked conformity and directly invoke the method

```
[canDo moveAlongX:1 andY:1];
```

Doing so you achieve both, you get rid of the warning and you can pass `int` directly without using `NSNumber`.